# Schtasks doesn't find scheduled task

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

using `schtasks /query /tn taskname` or `schtasks /delete /tn taskname` doesn't seem to find my task, always returns "The system couldn't find the specified task"
.

However, if i do a `schktasks /query` it shows the task, i've tried providing the fullpath to the /delete method, however the error was the same.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tasks are organized in folders so it is necessary to specify a full path of the task, otherwise only the root tasks will be listed:

> schtasks /query /v /fo list /tn \Microsoft\Windows\Wininet\CacheTask

```
Folder: \Microsoft\Windows\Wininet
HostName:                             ZOO
TaskName:                             \Microsoft\Windows\Wininet\CacheTask
Next Run Time:                        N/A
Status:                               Running
Logon Mode:                           Interactive/Background
Last Run Time:                        25.08.2015 20:02:17
Last Result:                          267009
Author:                               Microsoft
Task To Run:                          COM handler
Start In:                             N/A
Comment:                              Wininet Cache Task
Scheduled Task State:                 Enabled
Idle Time:                            Disabled
Power Management:
Run As User:                          Users
Delete Task If Not Rescheduled:       Enabled
Stop Task If Runs X Hours and X Mins: Disabled
Schedule:                             Scheduling data is not available in this format.
Schedule Type:                        At logon time
Start Time:                           N/A
Start Date:                           N/A
End Date:                             N/A
Days:                                 N/A
Months:                               N/A
Repeat: Every:                        N/A
Repeat: Until: Time:                  N/A
Repeat: Until: Duration:              N/A
Repeat: Stop If Still Running:        N/A
```

> schtasks /delete /tn \Microsoft\Windows\AppID\test

```
WARNING: Are you sure you want to remove the task "\Microsoft\Windows\AppID\test" (Y/N)? y
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "\Microsoft\Windows\AppID\test" was successfully deleted.
```

Using `/f` (force action) switch:

> schtasks /f /delete /tn \Microsoft\Windows\AppID\test

```
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "\Microsoft\Windows\AppID\test" was successfully deleted.
```

The path is shown in the output of `schtasks /query` after `Folder:` label.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, i tried that before but for some reason since my system is not in english, when it asked for prompt to confirm (yes or no) it asked as in my language (sim/não) and when i specified S for "yes" it failed, however if i put "y" it works.

Thanks again, the only examples i could find didn't specify the full path, so it was a bit confusing.

Comment: Add `/f` flag to force-delete the task.